# Trouble making a ListView where each item displays an ArrayList of a model

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, timer, adapter

I am working with alarms I have the whole Alarm System set up (models, DB, service, receiver, etc.) but that is besides the point.

I am grouping each alarm in an arraylist called "matchingAlarms" based on their repeating days (sunday-saturday) which is based on the users input. *I got this part down, No Problem here*

Now with that matchingAlarms Arraylist I am trying to make a ListView where EACH item in that ListView shows the Alarm Name and Alarm Time for each index of that arraylist (I want them to change in the ListView with a Timer).

> Example:
>
> > I have 1 alarm: 8 AM - 11 PM, Repeating Days: Sun-Thurs
> >     **AND** 1 alarm 9 AM - 12 PM, Repeating Days: Fri-Sat

Each one of those alarms are in an index of matchingAlarms Arraylist,
so the matchingAlarms size is 2.

I think I mentioned everything, now for the code.

AlarmListAdapter:

```
public class AlarmListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static Context mContext;
private List<AlarmModel> mAlarms;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<AlarmModel>> mMatchingAlarms = new ArrayList<ArrayList<AlarmModel>>();
private ArrayList<AlarmModel> grouped = new ArrayList<AlarmModel>();

private Animation anim;

AlarmModel model;
TextView txtTime,txtName,sun,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat;
ToggleButton btnToggle;
int matchingAlarmsIndex = 0;
int groupIndex = 0;
int itemIndex;

public AlarmListAdapter(Context context, List<AlarmModel> alarms, ArrayList<ArrayList<AlarmModel>> matchingAlarms) {
    mContext = context;
    mAlarms = alarms;
    mMatchingAlarms = matchingAlarms;
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.right_left);
}

public AlarmListAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public void setAlarms(List<AlarmModel> alarms) {
    mAlarms = alarms;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mMatchingAlarms != null) {
        return mMatchingAlarms.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<AlarmModel> getItem(int position) {
    if (mMatchingAlarms != null) {
        return mMatchingAlarms.get(position);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (mAlarms != null) {
        return mAlarms.get(position).id;
    }
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_name);
    txtTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_time);
    sun = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_sunday);
    mon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_monday);
    tue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_tuesday);
    wed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_wednesday);
    thur = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_thursday);
    fri = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_friday);
    sat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_saturday);
    btnToggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_item_toggle);

    grouped = getItem(position);


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            ((AlarmListActivity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if ((groupIndex + 1) <= grouped.size()) {
                        model = grouped.get(groupIndex);
                        updateTimeAndDates(model);
                        groupIndex++;
                    }
                    if ((groupIndex + 1) > grouped.size()) {
                        groupIndex = 0;
                    }
                    Log.i("", String.valueOf(groupIndex));
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 2500);



    return view;
}

private void updateTextColor(TextView view, boolean isOn) {
    if (isOn) {
        view.setTextColor(Colors.IndianRed);
    } else {
        view.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }
}

private void updateTimeAndDates(AlarmModel model) {
    txtName.setText(model.name);
    txtName.startAnimation(anim);
    txtTime.setText(DietDoctor.to12Hours(model.timeHour, model.timeMinute));
    txtTime.startAnimation(anim);

    updateTextColor(sun, model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SUNDAY));
    updateTextColor(mon, model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.MONDAY));
    updateTextColor(tue, model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.TUESDAY));
    updateTextColor(wed, model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.WEDNESDAY));
    updateTextColor(thur, model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.THURSDAY));
    updateTextColor(fri, model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.FRDIAY));
    updateTextColor(sat, model.getRepeatingDay(AlarmModel.SATURDAY));

    btnToggle.setChecked(model.isEnabled);
}

}
```

AlarmListActivity:

```
public class AlarmListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private AlarmListAdapter mAdapter;
    private AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(this);
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean fromSettings;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<AlarmModel>> matchingAlarms = new ArrayList<ArrayList<AlarmModel>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra("FromSettings"))
        fromSettings = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("FromSettings");

        mContext = this;

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarmlist);

        setGroups();

        mAdapter = new AlarmListAdapter(this, dbHelper.getAlarms(), matchingAlarms);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
...

public void setGroups() {
        ArrayList<AlarmModel> group = new ArrayList<AlarmModel>();
        List<AlarmModel> mAlarms = dbHelper.getAlarms();
        for (int i = 0; i < mAlarms.size(); i++) {
            if ((i + 1) != mAlarms.size()) {
                boolean result = Arrays.equals(mAlarms.get(i).getRepeatingDays(), mAlarms.get(i + 1).getRepeatingDays());
                Log.i("Result", Boolean.toString(result));
                if (result) {
                    if (i == 0)group.add(mAlarms.get(i));
                    group.add(mAlarms.get(i+1));
                }
                if (!result) {
                    if (i == 0)group.add(mAlarms.get(i));
                    matchingAlarms.add(group);
                    group = new ArrayList<AlarmModel>();
                    group.add(mAlarms.get(i+1));
                }
            }

            if ((i + 1) == mAlarms.size()) {
                boolean result1 = Arrays.equals(mAlarms.get(i).getRepeatingDays(), mAlarms.get(i - 1).getRepeatingDays());
                Log.i("Result_1", Boolean.toString(result1));
                if (result1) {
                    group.add(mAlarms.get(i));
                    matchingAlarms.add(group);
                }
                if (!result1) {
                    matchingAlarms.add(group);
                    group = new ArrayList<AlarmModel>();
                    group.add(mAlarms.get(i));
                }
            }

        }
        Log.i("Matching Alarms", String.valueOf(matchingAlarms.size()));
        Log.i("Group", String.valueOf(matchingAlarms.get(0).size()));
        Log.i("UnGrouped", String.valueOf(mAlarms.size()));

    }
```

I think the real problem lies in the getView Method and the timer within it.
As you can see from the picture below i only got Fri-Sat going. The first item should have the alarms with repeating days: Sun-Thurs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that is happening because `getView` is getting called several times (at least once for each item on the `ListView`).

So on your adapter when you're using all those `TextView` field, you're overwriting their reference every time, and only the last one is really correct.

To fix that the best would be to apply a `Holder` pattern. If you google for it you'll find about a million and five hundred thousand examples of it and how it works.

```
private static class Holder {
    AlarmModel model;
    TextView txtTime,txtName,sun,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat;
    ToggleButton btnToggle;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
}
```

and then update your `updateTimeAndDates` to be:

```
updateTimeAndDates(Holder h) {
     h.timer.cancel();
     h.timer.purge();
     // carry on updating the values and create the re-schedule the updates.
}
```

also I would suggest against timer and just use a `.postDealayed(Runnable, long);` on the view. Timers are not very well done classes at all.